# Double summation over the triangle $0 \leq k \leq j \leq m$

Tags: sequences-and-series

https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/ says

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{j=k}^{m}{a_{k,j}}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{j}{a_{k,j}}
$$

Is this correct or is it a typographic error? It feels like one side should have $a_{m-k,j}$ or $a_{k,m-j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.  Think of $a_{k.j}$ as entries in a square matrix.  The sum is over the main diagonal plus all terms where $j\gt k$.

Comment: Thanks. Just need to triple think if it to see... not an identity I’ve an intuitive feel for